# How to handle Partials in a Sitemap?

Tags: sitemap, xml-sitemap, site-structure

Let's say I've got all of my pages laid out like

`root/page.php` combined with `root/content/page.php`

page.php includes:

- header.php
- footer.php
- sometemplate.php
- menu.php
- submenu.php
- /content/page.php

This way the only thing generally in the /content/page.php is very basic html markup and the copy.

For my sitemap would I list `http://www.root.com/page.php` or `http://www.root.com/content/page.php`?

Comment: You index whatever the visitor is viewing and not by-parts of your template. Footer, Header, Menu, Submenu etc should not be accessible directly by navigating to those files, but rather so `index.php` or `page.php`. You shouldn't need to even think about those files if you have correctly made those files by using good PHP practices.

Comment: @SimonHayter ---- Thanks, thats what I figured just wasn't sure on the content since its the part that actually gets changed, any reason you left that as a comment instead of an answer?

Comment: I normally leave a comment if I don't have time to write a better quality answer, anyhows, made time and there you go :) thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should index whatever the visitor is viewing and not internal by-parts of your template.

Files such as `footer.php`, `header.php`, `nav.php`are commonly called using PHP Include, because of the nature of the way PHP includes work, the visitor doesn't see any of these files but rather a complete render of all parts, it is the final outcome that you should want to index.

Using good PHP practices your [php template files should not be directly accessible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409496/prevent-direct-access-to-a-php-include-file), so even if you did include them in your sitemap, Google and other search engines would not index those pages, because the server should be returning a valid server-side response with either a [404 not found](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404), or [403 forbidden](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403).